# Knitr, convert to base64 and CSS style

Tags: html, css, r, knitr

I'm a little new to this great library (and HTML) so this might be a noob question.

I have a situation that I'm unable for figure out - how can I add some CSS styling to an image while also encoding it in base64? This is the code in my Rmarkdown file (which I pass to `knit2html`) -

```
<img src="SomeImage.png", width = "75%", border = "2"> # converts to base64 with width and border correctly applied
<img class="displayed", src="SomeImage.png"> # does not convert to base64, points to local path with style correctly applied
```

Is there any way to get the second one to convert to base64 while applying the style too? Or am I doing something wrong?

`SessionInfo`, if needed -

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

other attached packages:
 [1] markdown_0.6.5   xtable_1.7-1     knitr_1.5        audio_0.1-4      ggplot2_0.9.3.1 
 [6] scales_0.2.3     stringr_0.6.2    reshape2_1.2.2   reshape_0.8.4    plyr_1.8        
[11] data.table_1.9.2
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<style>
.displayed { border: solid 1px; }
</style>

<img src="Rplot001.png" class="displayed">
```

Comment: Because base64 conversion takes place for the regexp: `reg <- "<\\s*[Ii][Mm][Gg]\\s+[Ss][Rr][Cc]\\s*=\\s*[\"']([^\"']+)[\"']"`